# Run nodemon in docker (MERN - docker-compose)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a container that runs a MERN application. In my frontend container I'm running react, and hot-reloading is working as suposed to, but in my backend container, I can't seem to find a solution for dynamic updates in my code. I'm trying to use nodemon package, but I don't know if I'm making things right. If I try to run my docker with nodemon active i'm getting errors.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.4",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0"
  }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    client:
        image: mhart/alpine-node:12
        build: ./client      
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        working_dir: /client
        volumes:
            - ./client:/client
        entrypoint: ["npm", "start"]
        links:
            - api
        networks: 
            - mynetwork
    api:
        build: ./api
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        working_dir: /api
        volumes:
            - ./api:/api
            - /api/node_modules 
        depends_on: 
            - mongodb
        networks:
            - mynetwork
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        container_name: mongodb
        volumes:
            - ./data-node:/data/db
        ports: 
            - 27017:27017
        command: mongod --noauth --smallfiles
        networks: 
            - mynetwork
networks:
    mynetwork:
        driver: bridge
```

**Dockefile** (backend)

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12

WORKDIR /api

COPY package*.json /api/

RUN npm install

COPY . /api/

EXPOSE 80

# CMD ["npm", "start"]

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**error output** (I have nodemon installed globally)

```
sh: nodemon: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! api@0.0.0 dev: `nodemon ./bin/www`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the api@0.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: The error is clear - it cannot find executable. You should try logging into the container and try to find out whether `nodemon` was installed or not and if it's location on the `PATH` environment variable. There're two ways to log into container: you can log into running container (`docker exec -it <container> ash`) or start a new container with a shell (`docker run -it <image> ash`).

Comment: Check your volumes on your api service in docker-compose.yml. It's a bit odd considering you are using a relative path on the api, but not on the node_modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a nodemon in your container. You need install it before. Insert `npm i -G nodemon` after `COPY package*.json /api/` in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem. I was missing the nodemon dependency inside my container.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `nodemon bin/www`, this mean you have to install `nodemon` as a npm global module. Maybe you have already installed `nodemon` in your local machine, but now, you call `nodemon bin/www` in your container instead of your local machine, then you get back `nodemon: not found`.

To solve your issue, I think you only need to change `dev` script in your `package.json` file to

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon bin/www"
```

Because I see you have already put `nodemon` module in your `devDependencies`, this command will use directly `nodemon` instance in your `node_module` folder instead of `nodemon` at global.